# two particular symbols

Tags: symbols

I have those two symbols: [image]
How can create those in LaTex?

Comment: Is the second one `\prod`?

Comment: unfortunately No

Comment: Should they behave the same as `\prod`? Can you give an on-line reference?

Comment: Axiomatic Set Theory - Patrick Suppes, pages: 83,84,85,86

Comment: You can make use of `\rule`s or `picture` mode (or even TikZ) to hand made them ;)

Comment: Egreg, maybe have you right.. pardon

Comment: @mle `\Pi`, or `\prod` for the second one, and the first one could be `\mathbf{I\!I}`? Probably just `\Pi` and `\mathbf{II}` after checking again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried the formula at the bottom of page 85 in [Google books](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=suppes%20axiomatic%20set%20theory&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=suppes%20axiomatic%20set%20theory&f=false)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\DPiA}{\mathbf{II}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DPiB}{\mathbf{I\mspace{-1mu}I}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DPiC}{{\mathrlap{\amalg}\Pi}}

\begin{document}
First version:
\[
A \rightarrow (\Pi = \DPiA(R) \leftrightarrow \mathsf{R}(\Pi) = R)
\]

Second version:
\[
A \rightarrow (\Pi = \DPiB(R) \leftrightarrow \mathsf{R}(\Pi) = R)
\]

Third version:
\[
A \rightarrow (\Pi = \DPiC(R) \leftrightarrow \mathsf{R}(\Pi) = R)
\]
\end{document}
```

Choose the one you like best, I'd prefer the third one.

[image]

Comment: Wow.. your answer is perfect! Danke! ;)

Comment: @mle My impression is that the symbol with two I's is a cheap mock up by the publisher, for lack of an adequate character.